# Android raising EPERM (Operation not permitted) when attempting to send UDP packet after network connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

When responding to a `SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` broadcast and attempting to send a UDP packet, the exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
   at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:542)
   at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:511)
   at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:184)
   at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:305)
   at com.mycompany.app.ServiceClass.discover(ServiceClass.java:355)at com.mycompany.app.ServiceClass.access$600(ServiceClass.java:39)
   at com.mycompany.app.ServiceClass$StateMachine.run(ServiceClass.java:242)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
   at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
   at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:211)
   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:278)
   at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:509)
   at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:184) 
   at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:305) 
   at com.mycompany.app.ServiceClass.discover(ServiceClass.java:355) 
   at com.mycompany.app.ServiceClass.access$600(ServiceClass.java:39) 
   at com.mycompany.app.ServiceClass$StateMachine.run(ServiceClass.java:242) 
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

is thrown by Android. However during debugging or if a `Thread.sleep()` call of ~300ms is added prior to attempting to send the packet, the exception isn't raised. It seems to be an issue of simultaneous access to the `Socket.send()` method immediately after Android establishes a network connection. Debugging the program only one call is made to the `send()`, so I'm confident the issue is related to interaction between the OS and my service.

The offending code is similar to:

```
public class ServiceClass extends Service {
    private static final byte[] MSG_BYTES = "My string to send".getBytes();
    private ConnectionMonitor mConnMonitor;

    public void onCreate {
        super.onCreate();
        // Create new thread to handle broadcast and register receiver
        mConnMonitor = new ConnectionMonitor();
        mConnMonitorThread = new HandlerThread("ConnectionMonitor",
                                               Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND)
        mConnMonitorThread.start();
        Looper connMonitorLooper = mConnMonitorThread.getLooper();
        Handler connMonitorHandler = new Handler(connMonitorLooper);
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)
        registerReceiver(mConnMonitor, netIntentFilter, null, connMonitorHandler);

    private void sendPacket() {
        DatagramSocket sock = new DatagramSocket(); // Actually wrapped in try-catch
        try {
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(MSG_BYTES, MSG_BYTES.length,
                    InetAddress.getByName("239.255.255.250"), 1900);
            sock.send(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
             // This is the exception being raised
        }

    public class ConnectionMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            SupplicantState supplicantState =
                    intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NEW_STATE);
```

Could the network being taking more time to initialize after the Supplicant `COMPLETED` broadcast is sent or more likely related to threading within my service?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.  Have you found any clue?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the best workaround I found was adding that ~300ms delay through `Thread#Sleep`, which was acceptable for my application (the application was just used in-house on a small range of devices).

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will make the app try again after a delay if this exception happens.